# Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers" which has no default value while ksql deploying ksqldb-server docker-compose image on fargate

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, ksqldb, aws-msk

I have managed to deploy ksqldb server on an ec2 instance with msk kafka as kafka server using `docker-compose` and its working perfactly(able to connect using python KSQL API client and access topics and stream in msk`.

```
version: '2'

services:
  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.14.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: b-1.ksql-kafka-tesing.boqxnyhyk.c2.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9092,b-2.ksql-kafka-tesing.byuuttoqxnk.c2.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9092,b-3.ksql-kafka-tesing.boqxyytuytutnk.c2.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9092
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
```

But when I deploy this docker image below on AWS FARGET with proper cluster and task definiation it gives following error log on cloudwatch log

```
2021-01-19T21:16:50.425+05:30   ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2021-01-19T21:16:50.425+05:30   (io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig:354)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   [2021-01-19 15:46:53,413] ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:68)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get Kafka cluster information

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaClusterUtil.getKafkaClusterId(KafkaClusterUtil.java:107)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:605)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.createExecutable(KsqlServerMain.java:161)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:61)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers" which has no default value.

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:478)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:468)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:108)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:142)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig.<init>(AdminClientConfig.java:233)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:74)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.DefaultKafkaClientSupplier.getAdmin(DefaultKafkaClientSupplier.java:41)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at io.confluent.ksql.services.ServiceContextFactory.lambda$create$1(ServiceContextFactory.java:58)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:164)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at io.confluent.ksql.services.DefaultServiceContext$MemoizedSupplier.get(DefaultServiceContext.java:176)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at io.confluent.ksql.services.DefaultServiceContext.getAdminClient(DefaultServiceContext.java:116)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at io.confluent.ksql.services.LazyServiceContext.getAdminClient(LazyServiceContext.java:33)

2021-01-19T21:16:53.417+05:30   at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaClusterUtil.getKafkaClusterId(KafkaClusterUtil.java:102)
```

I have also enabled port 8083, 8088 , 80 in farget container while adding docker image in the container.

Not able to find out why the same docker compose image is not running on farget but running on ec2 machine without error.

Can anybody help me with this ? I am totally new to ksql and aws farget too. Thanks in advance

PS:  I have followed this tutorial to deploy a docker image on farget [Deploy Docker Image on Farget using ECR and ECS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzsSjcyN3MI&t=610s)

Comment: Can you edit your question to detail how you're deploying to Fargate please? `Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers"` sounds like you've made an error in passing the necessary config, but it's hard to say without seeing how you've done it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzsSjcyN3MI&t=610s

I followed this tutorial to deploy a docker image on farget with configurations accordingly @RobinMoffatt

Comment: also you can KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS in docker-compose file which is working on a ec2 machine @RobinMoffatt

Answer (score 0):

Those environment variables in docker-compose was not getting read from the the image in the container. had to specifically mention the environment variable and value while adding the container in farget deployment.

Working perfectly ow.

Comment: What values did you need to mention?